# Cannot execute binary file

Tags: linux

I'm trying to install JasperReports Server 4.1 on Linux ubunto (release 11.04) and have following message:

> `-bash: ./jasperreports-server-cp-4.1.0-linux-x64-installer.run: cannot execute binary file`

Is any idea what should I do in order to insall Jasper?

Previously, I installed JasperReports Server 4.0 on Linux Red Hat without any problem. Is it related specifically to Linux ubuntu?

---

Here are the output for the commands `uname` and `ls -al`:

#### `uname -a`

> `Linux 64-cncrclinrpts 2.6.38-11-generic-pae #48-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jul 29 20:51:21 UTC 2011 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux`

#### `ls -al jasperreports-server-cp-4.1.0-linux-x64-installer.run`

> `-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 329844862 2011-09-09 09:11 jasperreports-server-cp-4.1.0-linux-x64-installer.run`

Answer (score 4):

You are trying to run a 64-bit binary on a 32-bit system.

Your `uname -a` indicates you are running a 32-bit kernel, and the filename you are trying to run gives the clue "x64".  Running `file` on this file will give you the whole story.

You probably want [jasperreports-server-cp-4.1.0-linux-x86-installer.run](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jasperserver/files/JasperServer/JasperServer%204.1.0/jasperreports-server-cp-4.1.0-linux-x86-installer.run/download)

Alternatively, you can run the installer you have on a 64-bit Linux system.

Comment: Thank you, PDO.
I installed successfully 32-bit edition.
Thank you for help.
Best Regards.

Answer (score 2):

This might indicate that an interpreter doesn't exist, although on my system I get a different (more useful) error message through some extra magic `bash` must have added.

```
$ cat > test.sh <<EOF
#!/bin/nonexistent/sh
echo "Hi."
EOF
$ chmod u+x test.sh
$ ./test.sh
-bash: ./test.sh: /bin/nonexistent/sh: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

It'd be helpful if you'd learn a bit more about this file: what does `file jasperreports-server-cp-4.1.0-linux-x64-installer.run` say? If it says it is a dynamic elf binary, what does `ldd jasperreports-server-cp-4.1.0-linux-x64-installer.run` say?

Comment: Still wondering what `file jasperreports-server-cp-4.1.0-linux-x64-installer.run` says. The `ldd` output suggests to me that it's interpreted but I don't know what the interpreter is.

Answer (score 0):

```
chmod +x jasperreports-server-cp-4.1.0-linux-x64-installer.run
```

then attempt to run it again, if it still doesn't work what is the ls -al for the file.

Comment: What is the output of uname -a?  You probably are missing libraries for the 64 bit version.

Answer (score -1):

You could run `strace ./jasperreports-server-cp-4.1.0-linux-x64-installer.run` to see what really happens there.